# How do PostgreSQL indexes reference rows?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, storage, postgresql-9.6

Do indexes in PG store some type of row internal ID, or store the row's primary key?

I am deducing it must be an internal row ID since tables don't have to have PK's. However, I can't find a specific answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row has an internal "address" stored in the system column `ctid` (very similar to Oracle's `rowid`). This ctid value is stored in the index.

More details are in the manual:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html#HEAPTUPLEHEADERDATA-TABLE

You can select the column if you want:

```
select ctid, t.*
from your_table t;
```

Comment: So any update to a row will require an index update as the ctid will change, right?

Comment: @IamIC: only if the update changes indexed columns. If not, Postgres can use a "HOT" (heap-only-tuple) update: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT See also [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84859/1822) and [this Postgres wiki article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Interaction_with_HOT)